# Can Ninject create standalone object?

Tags: dependency-injection, singleton, ninject

I need to instantiate an object that no other object needs to reference and I want it to live as long as application is running.
It will be using other services but no one else needs it's services.

Is it possible to let ninject create one such object at the beginning and maintain it in the memory for me or do I need to store it somewhere? How can I setup ninject to that it will create my instance and hold it until exit?

If so, what is your opinion on this practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, ninject does not provide such functionality out-of-the-box.
However, when you doo

```
IBindingRoot.Bind<FooService>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

and then one single get:

```
IResolutionRoot.Get<FooService();
```

that's enough to make ninject keep the same object alive until the kernel is disposed.
You don't need to keep a reference.

---

You could also use the [DependencyCreation Extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.dependencycreation) to tie the lifetime of the `FooService` to another service/object.

Like so:

```
IBindingRoot.Bind<SomeSingletonWhichIsInstantiatedAtTheBeginning>().To<...>();
IBindingRoot.DefineDependency<SomeSingletonWhichIsInstantiatedAtTheBeginning, FooService>();
IBindingRoot.Bind<FooService>().ToSelf().InDependencyCreatorScope();
```

This results in `FooService` being instatiated when `SomeSingletonWhichIsInstantiatedAtTheBeginning` is instantiated and also "disposed" of when `SomeSingletonWhichIsInstantiatedAtTheBeginning` is disposed/unreferenced.

However, beware of circular dependencies!

---

Yet another way would be to use the `OnActivation` feature to achieve something equivalent to what was done before:

```
IBindingRoot.Bind<FooService>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();

IBindingRoot
     .Bind<SomeSingletonWhichIsInstantiatedAtTheBeginning>()
     .To<...>()
     .OnActivation((context, service) => ctx.Kernel.Get<FooService>());
```

This ties the instantiation of `FooService` to the instantiation of `SomeSingletonWhichIsInstantiatedAtTheBeginning` and gets rid of `FooService` when the kernel is disposed.